# UWP C# app calling Windows Runtime Component written in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, c++-cx

I am trying to create a **Windows Runtime(WinRT)** Component written in C++(c++-cx) which can be called from my UWP C# app. I followed this [MSDN Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-basic-windows-runtime-component-in-cpp-and-calling-it-from-javascript-or-csharp)

 It all went fine. I am able to build & run the code/sample specified in the above link on both Windows-10 Desktop & Mobile

 I then tried to create a even simpler WinRT Component. I followed the same steps as above tutorial. Created a Windows Runtime Component project (File->New->Project->Visual C++ ->Windows->Universal->Windows Runtime Component(Universal Windows)) 

Now my class has only one function, **getNum** which basically returns a **uint16**

 This is my Class header file

```
#pragma once
#include <collection.h>

namespace WRT_sample
{
    public ref class Class1 sealed
    {
        public:
              Class1();
              uint16 getNum();
    };
}
```

This is the corresponding cpp file:

```
#include "Class1.h"


using namespace WRT_sample;
using namespace Platform;

Class1::Class1()
{
}

uint16 Class1::getNum()
{
     return 100;
}
```

I am using the same class names(Class1.h & Class1.cpp) which VS-2015 provides when I create a new WinRT project. 

 This is how I make a call to WinRT class from my C# code:

```
namespace CS_WRT_sample
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
       public MainPage()
       {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            initWRT();
       }

       void initWRT()
       {
            try
            {
                var nativeObj = new Class1();
                var num = nativeObj.getNum();
                this.Result2.Text = "Num from Cpp: " + num.ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine("Num from Cpp: " + num);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                this.Result3.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to build & run my code on Desktop(x86/x64 Local Machine), but when I try to run on Mobile(x86 Emulator or ARM device), it fails with the following error:

> **Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in CS_WRT_sample.exe**
>   
> **The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:** 0x8007007E)**

This is the stack trace which I see:

> **System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
>     
>  at WRT_sample.Class1..ctor()
>     
>  at CS_WRT_sample.MainPage.initWRT()**

My VS-2015 details:

> MS Visual Studio Professional 2015
>   
>  Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
>   
>  MS .NET Framework
>   
>  Version 4.6.01038

I am not sure, why I am hitting the issue, as I followed the same steps mentioned in the MSDN tutorial.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I tried in my machine it works well in both local machine and x86 Emulator, is there any special steps you did?

Comment: Hi @2power10, Thanks for the response. That is strange. I copied my project to my friend's machine & ran it on his machine. He too was seeing the same behavior. No, I am not doing anything special. As I mentioned, I followed the same steps as listed in MSDN tutorial. I compared my C/C++ & Linker Command Line args with the MSDN tutorial's & both are the same. Basically I am just using Windows Runtime Component project template, & not modifying any settings/flags. I am not sure how to debug this issue now.

Comment: I made a demo, but couldn't reproduce your problem. Could you share a basic sample that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Hi @ElvisXia-MSFT, Thanks for the response. I have uploaded my entire sample here: (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dhvjyzkkixproro/AAD2GLeXYOAZ39w8kIqiBNHLa?dl=0). You can download and run it. You can see that if you try to run on either Debug/Release x86 mode on emulator, I get the error. Again I tried this sample on my friend's machine, he has VS Community Edition & he is seeing the same error as well. 2power10, you are welcome to try this sample as well.

Comment: could you provide a more complete stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will run into this if you use a direct reference to a C++ winmd, instead of a P2P reference. This is easy to check in your .csproj:

For example, your .csproj should not have this line:
    
        
          ..\Debug\Abc_def\Abc_Def.winmd

Instead, consider using something like:
    
          {1ee77824-eaa8-40f1-9b56-6f8ffa44e727}
          Abc_Def