# Deploying UWP app with WinRT/C++ component on Remote Machine running Windows 10

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-runtime, windows-11

I'm currently developing an Universal Windows SDK with a WinRT/C++ component/reference. To debug that, I've also created a simple UWP app.

I developed this on Windows 11 running Visual Studio 2022.

When debugging on my Local machine, everything works. I also have a second Windows Device, Microsoft Surface Go 3, running Windows 11, where everything works as expected.

However, when I downgraded the Surface device to Windows 10, I'm now seeing the following exception when trying to deploy to the Remote Machine:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<My-WinRT-Module' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
   at <My-WinRT-Class>..ctor()
```

When I made a release package and installed it on the Surface device, everything works. When I download Visual Studio on the Remote Machine and debug it directly, everything works.

This issue happens only in this specific scenario: Deploying from a Windows 11 machine to a Windows 10 Remote Machine.

I'm pulling my hair out over this one. Could I be missing some Visual Studio development tools on my main machine? Could a difference in .NET SDK be to blame? How even?

The only similar question I found was this one: [UWP C# app calling Windows Runtime Component written in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626173/uwp-c-sharp-app-calling-windows-runtime-component-written-in-c), but that doesn't really solve anything and is also five years old.

Comment: It may be a redistributable issue (typically MSVC Runtime, etc.). Try procmon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to check file access and determine what are the missing files (.dll) that cause the 0x8007007E error.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what was going on, but it seems to have a MSVC runtime issue. Thank you very much @SimonMourier!

Comment: More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/libraries/c-runtime-packages-desktop-bridge it's often a MSVCRT debug vs release issue. Developer compiles in debug, but MSVCRTD(ebug) is not installed on "normal" machines.